# Dell L501X Display Port Screen issue

Tags: resolution, monitor, screen

I got a Dell XPS L501X with a mini display port to VGA connector for my External Screen.
On Displays it shows me: Acer Technologies 24" (which is the monitor) but only lets me up to 1024x768 resolution (The native resolution of this monitor is 1920x1200).

I tried adding a new mode with xrandr, but when I applied it, it reverted back to 1024x768.
As far as I know, the display port is controlled by the Intel card, right?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Using Ubuntu 11.10 32bit

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new mode (I did this with l502x and it works for me)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions

What I did to get 1600x1050:

- cvt 1600 1050
- xrandr --newmode "1600x1050_60.00"  140.00  1600 1704 1872 2144  1050
  1053 1063 1089 -hsync +vsync
- xrandr --addmode DP1 1600x1050
- then Go to screen config and choose 1600x1050

Answer (score 0):

To follow the former answer, you can also use **NewRez** Script ( A script that uses the XRANDR utility for intel graphics). Download and instruction through here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/set-your-screen-resolution-higher-than-you-should-with-newrez/

But you should know that your problem comes likely from the **cable** itself.
You're trying to output a digital video stream to an analog port in your external monitor, then using a miniDP to VGA cable is legitimate. Yet, know that **most VGA adapters are not capable of driving high resolutions**, their maxiumum is often 1024x...
So even though, you use XRANDR to add a new mode and force it, this will not work unless you use a **high quality VGA adapter**.

Another solution is to use the miniDP to HDMI or miniDP to DVI cable, which will work out of the box as long as you have the adequate ports on your external monitor.
I posted about hardware support in Ubuntu for the Dell the XPS 15 in this post, it might help:
http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/dell-xps-15-l502x-ubuntu-linux/